# Elastic beanstalk environment variables encryption using KMS

Tags: java, spring, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-kms

I'm working on an application which is hosted on AWS elastic beanstalk. I'm storing a few keys and passwords as environment variables within elastic beanstalk. These variables are stored into java variables using @data and @value annotations. I want to encrypt these environment variables using KMS and decrypt it before storing it in the variable.

How should i achieve this?